# I can't find cross platform app Xamarin on visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have installed visual studio 2017 community properly with mobile development packge and I can't find cross platform app in c#

[image]

What can I do to install it ?

Comment: "Mobile development" does not equal Xamarin or cross-platform. Exactly what did you install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should review the [installation procedure documented by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows).

If you don't have the Xamarin menu under Help then you may have missed something. You can re-run the installer and change workflows to confirm you have all the required pieces. Note that additional steps are needed to build and deploy, although you see stuck at just the installation step if templates are missing.

Comment: thenk you ... the problem was that three programms .msi of xamarin.froms was corupted and the solution was a complet réinstall of windows operating system in an other partition the same programms .msi worked in the new OS

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that some files was **corrupted** because of a **faild complete unistallation of xamarin** ... so i prefered a speed and smart solution that can help me to continue my work so **i installed a new os windows in new partition** i **tried to install those files** , they worked on the new os so it's clear that xamarin will be installed properly **finaly i installed the hole visual studio** and **that worked** for me ... [image]